# How to use INSERT statement with WITH clause?

Tags: mysql, h2

My goal is to use WITH clause to insert data into multiple table.

What I've tried, step by step test:

1. Test with INSERT statement

```
INSERT INTO user VALUES (default, 'test2', 'test', 1);
Update count: 1
(2 ms)
```

2. Test with WHERE clause.

```
SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM organization_member WHERE user='628111234567' AND role='0');
1  
1
(1 row, 1 ms)
```

3. Test with WITH clause.

```
WITH temp AS (SELECT 1 FROM organization_member WHERE user='628111234567' AND role='0')

SELECT 1 FROM temp;
1  
1
```

**This is where things go wrong**
4. Test with WHERE and WITH clause

```
WITH temp AS (SELECT 1 FROM organization_member WHERE user='628111234567' AND role='0')

SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS (temp);
```

My expected result is the SQL statement should return a row.

My actual result is the database throws an error:

```
Syntax error in SQL statement "WITH TEMP AS (SELECT 1 FROM ORGANIZATION_MEMBER WHERE USER='628111234567' AND ROLE='0')

SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS (TEMP[*])"; expected "(, WITH, SELECT, TABLE, VALUES"; SQL statement:
WITH temp AS (SELECT 1 FROM organization_member WHERE user='628111234567' AND role='0')

SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS (temp) [42001-200] 42001/42001 (Help)
```

This is probably the solution I am goign to use

```
WITH temp AS (SELECT 1 FROM organization_member WHERE user='628111234567' AND role='0')

INSERT INTO user (default, 'test', 'test', 1) WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM temp)
INSERT INTO user_detail (default, 'test', 'test') WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM temp);
```

Comment: Is your database MySQL or H2?  They're not the same thing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I use MySQL for production and H2 for development.

Comment: Bad idea: _Always_ develop and deploy using the same database, unless there is a very valid reason to not be doing so (there usually isn't one).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen well noted. I will be trying to switch over MySQL for the development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a formal `SELECT` inside the `EXISTS` clause in the 4th example:

```sql
WITH temp AS (SELECT 1 FROM organization_member WHERE user='628111234567' AND role='0')

SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM temp);
```

Comment: Hi, my intention of using the WITH clause is to reduce the N+1 problem. Does this count as N+1 problem? I intent to create 2 - 3 lines with `INSERT` statement with WHERE EXISTS clause.

Comment: @kidfrom I have corrected your syntax.  I have no idea what you are really trying to do here, and the question didn't help me to figure that out.

Comment: Thank you, it does solve my problem. Anyway, I have write the possible solution I am going to use. What do you think about the SQL statement, performance-wise.

Comment: It is hard for me to say for certain.  CTEs should be used to avoid repetition of code, but also to make code more concise and easier to understand.  If you find that using CTEs makes things more convoluted, then don't use them.

Comment: Well noted. Isn't CTE equals to stored temporary table or it is just to avoid repetition of code?

Comment: It depends on the database.  On Postgres, CTEs are materialized, on SQL Server, they are not.